# Combination exam question answer verification

Tags: combinations

> A financial services company enforce a password system for their cloud
>   application such that all passwords must consist of 10 alphanumerics.
>   More precisely, passwords must contain 6 lower case letters and 4
>   digits in any order without repetition. How many different passwords
>   are possible using this system?

My way of calculating this is

26P6 which cover the 6 lower case letters

10P4 which cover the digits

26P6 * 10P4 = 8.35458...*10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an additional factor of ${10}\choose{6}$ corresponding to selecting slots for the letters.

Comment: @ paw88789: So it would look like this `26P6 * 10C6 * 10P4 ` because the first choice of characters has 10 slots